# Microsoft SQL Update all

Tags: php, sql

I need to update a table in SQL via php.
When i log in to my database and write:

```
UPDATE table1
SET whatiwant = whatiwant
```

it updates all. That what i want.
But when i write this in PHP, it is not working.

I need to give him a Where clause to execute it and i have to loop through all entries.

```
UPDATE table1
SET whatiwant = whatiwant
WHERE id = '1'
```

I need to update all the entries. Why is it not working?

Comment: The only reason I can think of is because `id` can be `NULL`.  You should use `1 = 1`.

Comment: Can you please provide full code? I don't think that you update same value to itself for all entries?

Comment: if you have different values for respective fields then use `id = id` otherwise use `1 = 1` , also if you want to make sure that query is proper then `echo` query without executing

Comment: @Justina I am creating a HASHBYTE, so every entry is different.

Comment: Can you put your PHP Code??

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
WHERE 1 = 1
```

to match all records.

or if there needs to be an Id on the left side use something that's impossible to match, e.g.:

```
WHERE Id <> -1
```

if you have id only positive numbers.

Comment: hard to say from the code snippet. Might be NULL (you can check via ISNULL(id, 0) = ISNULL(id, 0) - that should work in case id is NULL

Comment: Thx for the answer. I tried 1=1, id=id and also id <> -1 and id <> 1. Nothing worked ~~

Comment: then problem must lie somewhere else, can you share your PHP code? are you sure the query gets executed from PHP code?

Comment: yes i am sure that it is executed. Because i tried it with a where clause where i set the id to something and it has changed. Just when i remove the where, it is not working. Same code in the database without where is working

Comment: without seeing the PHP code its hard. Capture the UPDATE that is actually sent to the database. Do you use any PHP framework which might 'change' the UPDATE somehow? Which DB do you use (MySQL or some another). Also try WHERE TRUE

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run update all the time write your statement without `where` otherwise if you want this `SQL` statement do 2 different behavior, you have to write a `Stored Procedure` with a parameter @id :

- If a value pass to the parameter @id, it works well
- If you pass `null` to that, it updates all rows without any where clause

> ```
> SET ANSI_NULLS ON
> GO
> SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
> GO
> CREATE PROCEDURE SP
>   @id int =null
> AS
> BEGIN     
>   UPDATE table1
>   SET whatiwant = whatiwant
>   WHERE (id = @id OR @id IS NULL)
> END
> GO
> ```

Comment: thx for the answer. But i need it in php. Can u help provide me the variables/funtions? i am using sqlsrv